# Pull only a JSON serializable part of a DateTimeField into a queryset?

Tags: python, json, django, datetime, serialization

What is the most efficient way to get a JSON serializable part of the DateTimeField into a Django queryset?

Bigger picture is that I'm saving energy meter readings (IntegerField) + datetimes for multiple users and would like to show a logged in user's data in a django-graphos visualization. Ideally keeping the flexibility to switch graphs between day, week, month views.

I've got the graph to work nicely for a logged in user with the user_kwh integer and the user_id using the below in my view:

```
def graph(request):
        queryset = MeterReading.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        data_source = (ModelDataSource(queryset, fields=["user_id", "user_kwh"])) 
        chart = gchart.LineChart(data_source)
        context = {'chart': chart}
        return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', context)
```

But when I change user_id to user_kwh_timestamp (my name of the datetime field) it throws the TypeError: "datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 1, 21, 58, 2, tzinfo=) is not JSON serializable"

**Stuff I've tried so far**

- I've tried serializing the values in the queryset before passing them
  to the template with: `data_source = serializers.serialize('json', MeterReading.objects.all(), fields=('user_kwh_timestamp',))` 
  but that
  gives an AttributeError saying 'unicode' object has no attribute
  'get_header'.
- I've tried defining the queryset narrower with .values_list but that
  says "'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'user_kwh_timestamp'"
- I've found this Django documentation on updating multiple objects in a queryset, but it only shows how to update all with 1 string: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

From the Python datetime documentation it seems that strftime() and %b or %x could be a part of the solution, but at this point I'm confused on how/where to implement those https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects

I'm using Django 1.7.1 and Python 2.7.6 via ide.c9.io. 
First coding project and first question here so excuse any ignorance in contents, style or approach :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) lib serialize the result values (from queryset), specifying a [JSON encoder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder), in this case [DjangoJSONEncoder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/#serializing-django-objects). You must turn queryset into a list before serialize, or you may get some exception.

```
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

...

def graph(request):
    queryset = MeterReading.objects.filter(user=request.user).values()
    data = json.dumps(list(queryset), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    ...
```

Comment: thanks mauro!  that brought up 'str' object has no attribute 'user_kwh_timestamp' from graphos/sources/model.py in get_field_values (i've seen the 'has not attribute' more often).  although when I use another

Comment: [edited for more than 5 minutes..] so while we've created a list now, i've tried using graphos' SimpleDataSource instead of ModelDataSource.  it brings up no errors, but the visualization  renders into google.visualization.arrayToDataTable("[{\"user_id\": 1, \"id\": 1, \"user_kwh\": 49520, \"user_kwh_timestamp\": \"2013-12-01T21:58:02Z\"}, while the structure should be along the lines of google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["user_kwh_timestamp", "user_kwh"], [2013-12-01T21:58:02Z, 49520], etc.